# Error launching onPause()/onResume() android flash air

Tags: android, flash, android-intent, android-activity, air

I'm developing an app for android, using Flash Air with flash builder and flash cs6.

After I've loaded and SWF I need to put my app on background, and call again the application to foreground. That is because I observed an improve response of my application, it goes faster

I'm using this:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LAUNCHER;launchFlags=0x10000000;component=android.app.Activity.onPause();end"));
```

But other application is opened, in my case an email application